# Logo in the mobile menu bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I'm working on a bootstrap template, I created a `div class` with a logo, but when I tight the window of chrome, the logo is up above the mobile menu.

**My site (mobile version)**

[image]

*What I want the mobile version of my site to look like**

[image]

My code:

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="img/bulls-logo.png" class="img-responsive" width="500px" height="100px">
  </div>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> HOME<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> ATLETI<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> CALENDARIO GARE<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">
<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> AFFILIAZIONI<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> RISULTATI <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">
<i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> CONTATTI<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> SHOP<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```css
.logo
{background-color: #FFF;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 10px;}


.navbar
{margin-bottom:0px !important;
font-size: 12px;
: #000;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that your logo be inside your navbar, you should put your logo inside html code of the navbar.

Try to add this line inside your navbar header (and change img path):

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-left hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-sm"><img src="path/to/your/image.jpg"></a>
```

and add some classes to your extra logo div

```
<div class="logo">
  <img src="img/bulls-logo.png" class="img-responsive hidden-xs" width="500px" height="100px">
</div>
```

**EDITED** example :

```
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="img/bulls-logo.png" class="img-responsive hidden-xs" width="500px" height="100px">
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-left hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-sm"><img src="path/to/your/image.jpg"></a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> HOME<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> ATLETI<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> CALENDARIO GARE<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">
<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> AFFILIAZIONI<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> RISULTATI <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">
<i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> CONTATTI<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> SHOP<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Comment: i want logo in nav bar only in mobile, in full screen i want logo over the nav bar.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry I misunderstood you. I this case, you can add `hidden-xs` `hidden-sm`  `hidden-md` `hidden-lg` to hide when it's needed your extra div or image inside navbar. Note : I have updated my answer for example.

Comment: Following link can help you to understand what I mean http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: i try to place your code in my code, but the result is the same.
look this pic http://i67.tinypic.com/28lcpbc.jpg

aniway thanks for the help

Comment: Hmm. Well I have to make a jsfiddle to test it

Comment: Forgive me for this ugly style, i make it quick. But check image change on window resize : https://jsfiddle.net/rzquf1sw/

Comment: I have updated again answer to make it works like in jsfiddle example

Comment: I LOVE YOU!
THANKS THANKS THANKS!

PS: the carousel now in mobile mode is like this, you know why? http://oi63.tinypic.com/cj03l.jpg

Comment: Hard to say without more code, but I would say that carousel have height set to 100% and the image keep his original size or have width to 100% and height auto

Comment: Don't forget to validate my answer if it solves your original problem. If you have trouble with carousel now, may be it will better to open a new question to leave this one understandable.

Comment: You'r welcome ;) Here a link to help you to close the question http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, when this mobile view comes, so you have to edit the px. In my example the view is showed, when the width is below 720px.

```
@media (max-width: 720px) {
 .logo{
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
 }  

 .logo img{
   width: 100%;
   float: none;
  }
}
```

And in the `head`tag of your html-file you have to add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```